# What is the best way to create a large xml file with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I try to create a xml file with php.

As file is an extract of mySQL database, the recordset may contain around 90000 rows.
So generate the xml file is slow, around 50s.

I don't want to make a dump, but only create a file to send to Flashbuilder to create a dataprovider.

I try to use several process:

```
DOMDocument
XmlWriter
SimpleXMLElement
```

But with those methods, time to create file is the same.

I made another test on server side, with this directive : `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');`

Do you know another approach, to write large xml file too speed.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want to route your data through PHP? Maybe you can use the `mysqldump` ability to create the output in XML: See the [MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml) on this.

```
mysqldump -X yourDb yourTable
```

Comment: +1 nice - always use the correct tools for the job .... but you know the OP is going to complain its not in "their format" !!!

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump would be the best for this.

Else depends if you have a specific format for the files. The best way is probably just to iterate results and build the file "manually" with php. phpMyAdmin can also export xml. Something really simple would be ...

```
$rows = '<? xml... ?>';
$query = mysql_query(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $rows .= "<row>\n";
  foreach($row as $tag=>$val){
    $rows.= "<$tag>$val</$tag>\n";
  }
  $rows .= "</row>\n";
}

file_put_contents('sql.xml',$rows);
```

but you could very well be trying to do something that is just going to take time to process, and that php isn't the best tool for, i.e. `mysqldump`

Comment: Thanks but my goal is not do to a dump, but only display data on flex datagrid.

Comment: Then just use something similar to the above, and have it spit out the appropriate namespace:tag.